# cloudformation error: Received 1 FAILURE signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

Good day, I am using the AWS quick start for [linux-bastion](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-linux-bastion/blob/c8975af1f984fc71e2eeb8f239ae5550acacac57/templates/linux-bastion.template).
On changing the QSS3BucketName and QSS3KeyPrefix to the ones in my account it throws the error

> Received 1 FAILURE signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement

everything else in the stack is getting created, the script being pulled from the s3 bucket and user data being on the instance. The only issue is, autoscaling group fails to create despite providing the instance and running the user data. My guess is something is happening in the s3accesscreds which i am not able to fathom.

WHAT CAN BE THE CATCH?? would really appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: check in the stack if the IAM role `BastionHostRole` is created?

Comment: yes it is created.
cfn-init.log says that the b-bootstrap command failed.
can not figure out why.
is it because i am using my own bucket?

Comment: Follow these [steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/deployment.html) to see if you missed anything

Comment: did it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You need to make sure that the bastion_bootstrap.sh file [here](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-linux-bastion/tree/master/scripts) is placed under the correct location in your bucket:

```
your-bucket-name/your-prefix/scripts/bastion_bootstrap.sh
```

And, of course, that the bastion_bootstrap script itself doesn't throw any errors. If it does, you'll see them in /var/log/cfn-init.log